# Docker volumes with Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I created a web project in Visual Studio 2017 with `Docker` support (my host is a Windows 10 machine). My image is based on Linux.

I have also created a webapi where the user can upload a picture. I have to store this picture on the file system. Currently, I'm doing like this:

```
File.WriteAllBytes(path, bytes); // path = /pictures/abc.jpg
```

and I can read the image back like this:

```
byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(path);
```

Everything works fine.

The problem is that the picture is stored in my container, but I would like to store it on my host (at the end, the docker image will be hosted on a Raspberry Pi and I have to store the pictures on a SD card).

I think that the solution is to use VOLUME. I tinker a bit with this instruction, but was not able to see the pictures in my host... How can I do that?

The solution is in this file

**docker-compose.override.yml**

```
version: '3'  

services:  
  abc:  
    environment:  
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development  
    ports:  
      - "5001:80"  
    volumes:  
      - .:/src  
      - ./pictures:/pictures  // <- The pictures folder is created where my docker project is
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use docker volumes. You can set the volume on host like below

```
docker run -v ~/Desktop/images:/my/images/inside/docker
```

Make sure your code writes to `/my/images/inside/docker` inside the container. This will move it to the host as well.

You can also use named volumes

```
docker volume create images

docker run -v images:/my/images ...
```

This will store images on a volume which will remain even container dies. But this will not store it on your host

**Edit-1**

So `docker-compose.override.yml` is what you need to use. Change the content of the file as

```
version: '3'  

services:  
  ci-build:  
    volumes:  
      - .:/src
      - ~/Desktop/images:/images/inside
```

This will combine both the files and then run it.

Comment: The trick is that I'm using Visual Studio (like written and tagged in the question). Everything is "magically" done for me when I'm starting a debugging session (F5), so actually, I never do a `docker run xxx`

Comment: There will be two generated files in your project, one related to `Dockerfile` and one probably related to compose. Are you able to locate them and add the content to your question? Look at the folder in explorer with view hidden files

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: It does not seem to work, but I'm not sure to understand what `~Desktop/images` means? also, my `File.WriteAllBytes` is writing in `'/pictures/abc.jpg'`, and I replaced your instruction with `'- ~/Desktop/pictures:/pictures'`

Comment: Mine is just an example path, so what you used it correct. Can you do add the volume entry in `docker-compose.ci.build.yml`. if that doesn't work then we can try named volumes instead

Comment: I added this entry in the `docker-compose.ci.build.yml` but it does not work. Is the folder `/Desktop/pictures` automatically created? I updated my question with all 4 docker files

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152862/discussion-between-tarun-lalwani-and-bidou).